# How do I access the nth element in a GAMS set?

Tags: indexing, dice, gams-math

I'm trying some alteration to the DICE2013 model. I define a set of a hundred values and want to access one value for each period t. I.e. if t=5, I want GAMS to return the fifth value in the set cereq.

```
sets    t        Time periods (5 years per period)      / 1*100 /
        cereq    list of multipliers                    /v1*v100/
```

I tried:

```
cereq(t)$ord((cereq)=t)
```

but that causes the program to crash.

How do I have to do this?

Many thanks

Comment: In GAMS, a set defined as `cereq(t)` would mean that the set `cereq` is a subset of `t`. So it crashes because you haven’t defined that subset relationship. Do you need `cereq` to be a set? And is there a reason why you can’t use `parameter`?

Comment: First, thanks for your reply. I thought if I had multiple values, I needed to define it as a set? So I can use paramters to define cereq    list of multipliers                    /v1*v100/? And how do I then access element t?

Comment: Yeah, if you use ‘parameter cereq(t)’, it defines a value of cereq for each t. So as long as t=1 maps to your v1, t=2 to your v2 etc. it will work. If you need to access an individual parameter, the syntax is ‘cereq(‘1’)’ for t=1, and so on. But most likely you need to define an equation or variable indexed by t. For this, you simply use cereq(t). E.g. VariableX(t) = cereq(t) * VariableY(t)